# VS loadtest throw out the exception LoadTestAgentResultsLateException

Tags: visual-studio, performance-testing, load-testing, msloadtest

I have two agents, agent1, agent2, but for some loadtest I only want it run in one agent, agent1. so I added "agent1" into the option "Agents to Use" in each scenarios. if I do this, the load test throw the error:

> Exception  LoadTestAgentResultsLateException   2   Results from agent 'agent1' were not received in time to be included in the overall results for a sampling interval. To avoid this error, increase the sample rate, or decrease the load on this agent.

Why?
Is there any other way, I can do to make the loadtest to run on part of the agents, rather than all of agents?